# Нужны ли в этом предложении запятые? И почему?

Tags: пунктуация

Ближе матери с ее безграничной любовью к нам никого нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь возможны оба варианта:

(1)  *Ближе матери с ее безграничной любовью к нам никого нет.*

(2)  *Ближе матери, **с ее безграничной любовью к нам**, никого нет.*

1. Оборот  «с ее безграничной любовью к нам»  можно считать определительным.

Предложение интересно тем, что его **структура и фонетика** позволяют использовать оба варианта – с обособлением и без обособления.

При обособлении оборот эмоционально **подчеркивается, выделяется**.

2. Выбор делается  **по тексту.**

В середине рассуждения, когда мы **раскрываем тему** и сравниваем какие-то варианты, лучше использовать необособленный оборот.

Если же это **вывод в конце статьи**, то обособленное и подчеркнутое определение будет выглядеть убедительнее.